# How to change the format of abbreviated month with a ending dot in my software R?

Tags: r

I am Peruvian and I'm learning to program in R

when I convert a character to date using the function as.Date I get NA.
This is because the abbreviated month does not have a point (Jul. Sep.)

> fecha<-c("06-jul-2015","06-sep-2012")
>
> as.Date(fecha, format="%d-%b-%Y")

[1] NA NA

Please. How I can do to R consider the abbreviated month without the point?

Thank You So Much

Comment: It works for me. Please restart your R and try again.

Comment: Month abbreviations are locale-dependent. Please run `Sys.getlocale()` and show us the output. You can also run `strftime(sprintf('2015-%02d-01',1:12),format='%b')` to get your locale's abbreviations directly.

Comment: This is the output
> Sys.getlocale()
[1]"LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252"
> strftime(sprintf('2015-%02d-01',1:12),format='%b')
 [1] "ene." "feb." "mar." "abr." "may." "jun." "jul." "ago." "sep." "oct." "nov." "dic."
My database has fields with dates as 01-Jul- 2014 (example).For this reason I was looking for the function "as.Date" obtains NA. Please. How I can do to R consider abbreviated month without dot?
months(http://as.Date ("2015-07-06"), T)
[1] "jul."
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566875/as-date-returning-na-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem yesterday. I just added the following line

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
fecha<-c("06-jul-2015","06-sep-2012")
as.Date(fecha, format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

and it works:

```
"2015-07-06" "2012-09-06"
```

Edit: for the Spanish and the dot in your comment:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish")
fecha<-c("06-ene.-2015","06-dic.-2012")
as.Date(fecha, format="%d-%b.-%Y")
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works with abbreviated months in english. But How is for case in spanish. What do I have that to modify in the function Sys.setlocale(). Because for my software R abbreviated months are "ene." "feb." "mar." "abr." "may." "jun." "jul." "ago." "sep." "oct." "nov." "dic." With a dot in the end