# as.Date returning NA after setting C locale

Tags: r, date

I am trying to set the C locale so that when I convert character objects to dates I don't get NA values. I got this solution [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566947/3736308), but it's not working for me. When I run the first commented line,

```
> lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(outfile) :
  incomplete final line found on 'tmp/Rtmp8AJy9P/Rhttpd9742ffa74dc'
[1] "C"
```

Then when I try to convert a character object to date, I still get an NA of class date.

```
> x <- "2015-02-15"
> z <- as.Date(x, "%Y-%B-%d")
> Sys.Setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
> z
[1] NA
```

Does anyone know what that warning means and if it could be affecting the conversion that I run later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
> x <- "2015-02-15"
> z <- as.Date(x, "%Y-%B-%d")
> Sys.Setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
> z
[1] NA
```

you have the wrong format as `%B` stands for the *textual, unabbreviated month*.  Witness:

```
R> as.Date("2015-02-15", "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2015-02-15"
R> as.Date("2015-February-15", "%Y-%B-%d")
[1] "2015-02-15"
R>
```

so I think your locale issue may be a distraction.

Comment: Yep, that solved it, thank you! Pesky date formatting always messing everything up.

Comment: Take a good look at my (rather recent) package [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) which tries really hard to take the _pesky_ out by not requiring formats for dates and times.

Comment: And thanks for accepting. You may also upvote (click on up-arrow).