# getting NA when using as.Date function

Tags: r

I'm trying to change date format using as.Date function like this:

```
as.Date("January 1, 1970", format="%B %d, %Y")
```

but I'm getting `NA`.

what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have the quote outside it.  It is working fine for me otherwise in `R 3.3.2` i.e. `as.Date("January 1, 1970", format="%B %d, %Y")#
[1] "1970-01-01"` (in windows 10)

Comment: for me (ubuntu 16.04, R 3.3.2) it returns `NA` as well.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15566875/3250126) which worked for me

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: OSX and R 3.3.2 here, working fine. I see that it seems to be a system locale issue, but would someone care to elaborate? Why do some locales work and others don't?

Comment: Thank you @Henrik!