# Read in dates with as.Date from character %d%b%Y

Tags: r, locale, as.date

This works:

```
as.Date("22JAN2010", format="%d%b%Y")
>"2010-01-22"
```

This doesn't:

```
as.Date("22MAR2010", format="%d%b%Y")
>NA
```

It breaks on MAR, MAY, OCT
and works for JAN, FEB, APR, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, NOV, DEC.

Coincidentally, my Windows 7 OS language is in Dutch, for which the date abbreviations would be MAA, MEI, OKT. But those don't work either.

Comment: Also works on OSX.

Comment: Tried `as.Date("22MAR2010", format="%d%b%Y", tz="UTC")` ?

Comment: change your locale with `Sys.setlocale(LC_TIME = 'en_GB.UTF-8')`

Comment: `as.Date("22MAR2010", format="%d%b%Y", tz="UTC")`
Gave an NA as well.

`> Sys.setlocale(LC_TIME = 'en_GB.UTF-8')
Error in Sys.setlocale(LC_TIME = "en_GB.UTF-8") : 
  unused argument (LC_TIME = "en_GB.UTF-8")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566875/as-date-returning-na-while-converting-from-ddmmmyyyy

Comment: @CClaire, that's the one, thanks! Didn't pop up in SO search for me.

Comment: Sorry, correct one should be: `Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME','en_GB.UTF-8')`

Answer (score -1):

You can find out what monthly abbreviations are going to be recognized with the in-built data object: `month.abb` which is internationalized.

```
 month.abb
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

The sessionInfo() function also returns the locale, which for me is:

```
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

... and could have gotten that single vector with `Sys.getlocale()` but I suspect you have something else set. As commented by @Jaap, the value is under your control with `Sys.setlocale`. The particular value of the 'LC_TIME' item should be used by `strptime` which is at the core of  the `as.Dat.character` function.

(The `Sys.setlocale` function has 2 named arguments "category" and "locale" which is why the first suggestion to use `Sys.setlocale(LC_TIME = "en_GB.UTF-8")` failed. It seemed to be typical R syntax to my eyes as well, since the usual pairlist formalism doesn't quote the names. I've made that mistake many times.)