# Convert Factor to Date (Year-Month)

Tags: r, date, dplyr

My data column looks like...

```
date
<fctr>
14-Jan
14-Feb
14-Mar
15-Jan
```

Just wondering how to turn this into a date, because when I punch this code in I get NA's

```
hand$date <- as.Date(hand$date, format = "%y-%b")

date
<fctr>
NA
NA
NA
NA
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe `library(zoo); as.Date(as.yearmon("15-Jan", "%y-%b"))`

Comment: Used both code above, and it just repeats the same date (2014-01-01)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP has requested to convert Year-Mon (without day of the month) to Date from a data.frame column which is a factor. Without day of the month, the date is incomplete which produces `NA`s.

There are various options available to deal with incomplete dates.

#### `as.Date()` with day of the month supplemented

As suggested in a similar form by [d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575641/convert-factor-to-date-year-month#comment78110811_45575641):

```
as.Date(paste0(hand$date, "-01"), "%y-%b-%d")
#[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2015-01-01"
```

#### `lubridate::ymd()`

The `ymd()` function of the `lubridate` package has a `truncated` parameter to parse incomplete dates:

```
lubridate::ymd(hand$date, truncated = 1L)
#[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2015-01-01"
```

Note that `lubridate` automatically has assumed the first day of each month.

#### `zoo::as.yearmon()` and `zoo::as.Date()`

The option to use the `as.yearmon()` function from the `zoo` package has already been suggested by [Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576648/3817004) and [statoptim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579453/3817004).

The answer of Sagan is incomplete because `as.yearmon()` returns an object of class `yearmon` but not `Date`:

```
str(zoo::as.yearmon(hand$date, "%y-%b"))
#Class 'yearmon'  num [1:4] 2014 2014 2014 2015
```

The answer of statoptim is unnecessarily complicated as `yearmon` can directly be coerced to `Date`:

```
zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(hand$date, "%y-%b"))
#[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2015-01-01"
```

Note that we have to use `zoo::as.Date()` if we haven't loaded `zoo` beforehand because base R's `as.Date()` doesn't know how to handle `yearmon` objects.

`zoo::as.Date()` has automatically assumed the first day of each month by default. The `frac` parameter can be used to control which day of the month is returned, e.g.,

```
zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(hand$date, "%y-%b"), frac = 1)
#[1] "2014-01-31" "2014-02-28" "2014-03-31" "2015-01-31"
```

returns the last day of each month.

#### Caveat

It might be the case that the current locale may influence the interpretation of the abbreviated month names (which might be the case in [statoptim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579453/3817004)).

[There's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566947/3817004) to a related question which suggests to check out the examples section of `?as.Date`:

```
## read in date info in format 'ddmmmyyyy'
## This will give NA(s) in some locales; setting the C locale
## as in the commented lines will overcome this on most systems.
## lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
x <- c("1jan1960", "2jan1960", "31mar1960", "30jul1960")
z <- as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y")
## Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
z
```

Answer (score 1):

Following will work.

```
> library(zoo)
> as.yearmon("14-Jan", "%y-%b")
[1] "Jan 2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

The zoo package documentation has the following example that also returns NA on my R

```
zoo::as.yearmon("mar07", "%b%y")
```

I am using gsub to replace "Jan" to "01". I see this is not the most efficient code but hope this helps you for now.

```
library(zoo)
df = data.frame(date = c("14-Jan", "14-Feb", "15-Jan"), stringsAsFactors = F)

month.abb
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" ....

month.num = substr( paste0("0", c(1:12)), start=c(rep(1,9), rep(2,3)), stop=3)
head(month.num)
# [1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06"

# can't think of or find ways to vectorize gsub 
for(i in 1:12) {
  df$date = gsub(df$date, pattern=month.abb[i], replacement=month.num[i])
}

as.Date(as.yearmon(df$date, format = "%y-%m"))
# [1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2015-01-01"
```

- update / comment since I don't have enough reputation to leave comments to [Uwe Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575641/convert-factor-to-date-year-month/45594364#45594364) 's answer. I found that "%b" (or passing month as abbreviation) does not work on my machine that have other language as operating system language. It works on another computer that has English as OS language. I do think question was posted because of the language issue. I was suggesting to convert to numeric values of month to bypass language issue not because of conversion to base date object.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out potential issues with the current locale. I've added a caveat to my answer. You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566947/3817004) on a related question useful for your case.