# Why does `as.Date` keep giving me `NA`s?

Tags: r, date, format, as.date

For some reason, `as.Date` keeps giving me `NA`s. Here's my code:

```
test <- "1996-04"
as.Date(test, format="%Y-%m")
```

This question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566875/as-date-returning-na-while-converting-from-ddmmmyyyy) didn't help me.

Comment: Because 'Date' needs a day too i.e. `as.Date(paste0(test, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')` also change the `$` to `%`

Comment: @akrun I'm gonna go with `as.yearmon`. Thanks guys