# why do as.Date() not converting, a string values column from dataframe, to values as date type?

Tags: r, as.date

I am trying converting a column having values as character from Dataframe, to date values. But after converting the column values turned into 'NA'.

*Here is my code:*

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
dvpact <- "https___covidlive.com.au_report_daily-vaccinations-people_act.html"
dvpactpage <- read_html(dvpact)
dvpactp <- dvpactpage %>% html_nodes("table.DAILY-VACCINATIONS-PEOPLE") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
dvpactp$Date <- as.Date(dvpactp$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
dvpactp
```

After the above conversion from *character* to *date*, the DATE column values shows **'NA'**. Can anyone help me on this issue, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566875/as-date-returning-na-while-converting-from-ddmmmyyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link doesn't work, but if the format is `27 Jun 22` like on this page: https://covidlive.com.au/report/daily-vaccinations/aus,

then you'll need to change the format argument inside this line:
`dvpactp$Date <- as.Date(dvpactp$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")`
to `format="%d %b %y"`

Comment: Error: Assigned data `as.Date(dvpactp$Date, format = "%d %b %y")` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 458 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `Date`.

Comment: Can you provide a working link? I think the problem is happening before the date conversion step